# Проблема с facebook API Marketing

Tags: facebook-api

У меня проблема с facebook API Marketing, когда я пытаюсь сделать данный POST запрос:
**act_ad_account_ID/users**

Я хочу дать своему юзеру analyst access к аккаунту, который установил у себя мое приложение. Но Api возвращает мне странную ошибку:
**(#10) Application does not have permission for this action**

Это происходит **лишь с одним** аккаунтом, со всеми остальными аккаунтами это работает без проблем. **Все аккаунты дали все разрешения приложению.**

Не могу найти подробных описаний данной ошибки в документации или где-либо еще. 
Кому-нибудь известно из-за чего вылазит данная ошибка?

Comment: Это СО на русском, переведите ваш вопрос.

Comment: Прошу прощения, перевел.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса тоже надо на русском.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку